# Default content editor in list form doesn't allow image alignment

Tags: sharepoint, moss, enhanced-rich-text

I need to be able to adjust the alignment of an image in an "Enhanced Rich Text Field" in an announcements list in MOSS 2007.  However, the default content editor in the edit form for the list doesn't provide a way to do that.  What's the fastest way for me to make sure users can align images?  My first thought was to customize the DispForm.aspx and EditForm.aspx pages, but they just have the ListForm web part in the content region and as far as I know, you can't customize the ListForm web part from the designer.

Answer (score 2):

You can't customize the LisForm web part, but you can add a "custom list form" to create a custom edit form. Maybe you haven't seen this article: http://weblogs.asp.net/jan/archive/2006/11/06/Custom-Edit-Forms-for-SharePoint-2007-Lists.aspx

Then you could do some javascript hackery to insert your own button which then calls something similar to existing `RTE_InsertImage` function to call a pop-up window and do whatever you need (you'll find this function in `12\template\layouts\1033\form.js`)

Answer (score 1):

I fail to see (or understand) your issue. I created a new announcements list, created a new item, inserted an image, aligned it to the right, viewed the item and it worked.

Then I proceeded to create a new custom column, choose multiple lines,enhanced rich text field, edited my list item, added an image, centered it, viewed and it was also working.

The only thing I noticed is that the "rich" control does not appears on non-IE browsers.